# Any ways to improve this implementation (significantly)?

Tags: c++

This is a piece of code I've written for a homework. It seems to work but I wonder if I missed something.

The task was to implement a function (here: `Countwords`) which counts all words in a char *. No library functions should be used.

```
namespace {

bool IsPrintable(char c) {
  return c >= '!' && c <= '~';
}

void SkipPrintable(const char *&s) {
  do {
    s++;
  } while (IsPrintable(*s));
}

bool IsWhiteSpace(char c) {
  return c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n';
}

void SkipWhitespace(const char *&s) {
  while (IsWhiteSpace(*s)) {
      s++;
  }
}

} // namespace

int CountWords(const char *s) {
  int count = 0;

  while (*s != '\0') {
    SkipWhitespace(s);

    if (IsPrintable(*s)) {
        count++;
        SkipPrintable(s);
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at ctype.h (http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha). You won't need to write isWhitespace etc. It won't make your program faster, but it will make the amount of code you write less.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: The OP mentioned that no library functions are allowed to be used

Comment: At first glance, it seems that your program will get stuck in an infinite loop if it encounters non-printable characters.

Comment: You might also want to include `'\r'` (carriage return) as a whitespace character.

Comment: Nitpick: The program will count isolated punctuation as a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solve this in linear complexity. One cannot do the same in less complexity. So you cannot **significantly** improve your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to significantly improve the algorithm, but you could make it a little bit cleaner by using a class to represent the state of the parser (e.g. current index and the string, itself, so that it does not need to be passed all over). You could also remove some of the redundancy between `SkipPrintable` and `SkipWhitespace` by implementing a single `SkipWhile` function that takes a `bool (*ShouldSkip)(char)` function pointer, and then passing in `&IsWhitespace` or `&IsPrintable`.

Answer (score 0):

i agree to all what is said above.
your code is good enough, the important thing is that its linear so its efficient
the only thing you might consider is maybe simplify it a little bit more like

```
bool newWord = true;
int count = 0;
while(*s != '\0')
{
    if(!IsWhiteSpace(*s))
    {
        if(newWord)
        {
            newWord = false;
            count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newWord = true;
    }
    s++;
}
```

but again, i see no problem with your implementation as is

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify algorithm (in terms of readability, not computational complexity), you can count word beginnings (where non-whitespace character either follows whitespace one, or is the first character in the string).

```
char previousCharacter=' ';
int wordsCount=0;
while(*s)
{
  if(IsWhiteSpace(previousCharacter) && !IsWhiteSpace(*s))
    ++wordsCount;
  previousCharacter=*s;
  ++s;
}
```